# Compute fastest growing/decresing portions in a series of plotted values

Tags: matlab, polyline

I have a series of plotted values (x, y). I'm searching for a way to identify the segments {(Xi, Yi), (Xi+1, Yi+1)} with the fastest growing/decresing rate.
[image: Plotted values]
In example image, these segments are tagged and have the following X coords (516, 550) for the fastest increasing segment and (620, 635) for the fastest decreasing segment. How can I define an algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the slope of each line segment.  Keep track of the maximum and minimum values of the slope.  These will correspond to the segments with the greatest rate of increase and the greatest rate of decrease, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The following example code should provide you with a way forward in solving your problem:

```
%Create x and y values
x = 1:0.5:20;
y = real((x-15).^2.2.*sin(x)-0.5*x);

%Plot
f1 = figure(1);clf
plot(x,y)

%Calculate derivative
dx = abs(conv(y,[1 -1],'same'));

%Find maximum change
[maxSlope idx] = find(dx==max(dx));

%Display derivative and maximum change points
hold on
plot(x+0.5,dx,'g')
plot(x(idx+1),y(idx+1),'*r')
grid on

legend('Data series','abs(Derivative)','Point of maximum change');
```

I have created a toy data set, and found the point where y changes the most. Note that equally spaced points (x increases linearly) is assumed here. Is your data evenly spaced?

Resulting plot:
[image]

Comment: I haven't a function to derive. I need a way to compute slope, without a derivative method.

Comment: Mind you, I have not derivated a function as such. I have made a numerical approximation to the derivative of the dataset given. I assume the you have access to the data which produced the figure you show in your post...?